# Print a list with the original style

Tags: python, list, printing, styles

I'm using python and I've got a txt database with values like  `24,50,55,5754`

Now I want to print for example the last three digits in the same style:

Output: `50,55,5754`

I created a list:

`str.split(",")`

And then want to print:

`print (str[1:4])`

However it then of course prints it like:
`['50', '55', '5754']`

I need it in a `xx,xx,xx`style because it needs to inserted like this in a HTTP adres.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) :

```
print(",".join(str.split(",")[1:4]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to join:

```
spl = s.split(",")
print (",".join(spl[1:])
```

If you just want to get the last three elements you can index the string:

```
s = "24,50,55,5754"
print(s[s.find(",")+1:])
50,55,5754
```

Comment: @BhargavRao, you did ;)